# Getting java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity after adding BigDecimal varibles.

Tags: java, android

All-
My project (calculating tips) worked fine until I added some BigDecimal variables to help with rounding. Now, when I hit "Calculate" the application force closes and the logcat says:

```
 06-01 14:24:21.246: W/dalvikvm(15364): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a4a1f8)
06-01 14:24:21.256: E/AndroidRuntime(15364): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-01 14:24:21.256: E/AndroidRuntime(15364): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
06-01 14:24:21.256: E/AndroidRuntime(15364):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3044)
06-01 14:24:21.256: E/AndroidRuntime(15364):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
06-01 14:24:21.256: E/AndroidRuntime(15364):    at android.view.View.onKeyUp(View.java:6078)
06-01 14:24:21.256: E/AndroidRuntime(15364):    at android.widget.TextView.onKeyUp(TextView.java:5636)
06-01 14:24:21.256: E/AndroidRuntime(15364):    at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2623)
06-01 14:24:21.256: E/AndroidRuntime(15364):    at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:5500)
06-01 14:24:21.256: E/AndroidRuntime(15364):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1246)
06-01 14:24:21.256: E/AndroidRuntime(15364):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1246)
06-01 14:24:21.256: E/AndroidRuntime(15364):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1246)
06-01 14:24:21.256: E/AndroidRuntime(15364):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1246)
06-01 14:24:21.256: E/AndroidRuntime(15364):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1879)
06-01 14:24:21.256: E/AndroidRuntime(15364):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1361)
06-01 14:24:21.256: E/AndroidRuntime(15364):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2324)
06-01 14:24:21.256: E/AndroidRuntime(15364):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1806)
06-01 14:24:21.256: E/AndroidRuntime(15364):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRootImpl.java:3327)
06-01 14:24:21.256: E/AndroidRuntime(15364):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleFinishedEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3300)
06-01 14:24:21.256: E/AndroidRuntime(15364):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2460)
06-01 14:24:21.256: E/AndroidRuntime(15364):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-01 14:24:21.256: E/AndroidRuntime(15364):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-01 14:24:21.256: E/AndroidRuntime(15364):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-01 14:24:21.256: E/AndroidRuntime(15364):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-01 14:24:21.256: E/AndroidRuntime(15364):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-01 14:24:21.256: E/AndroidRuntime(15364):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-01 14:24:21.256: E/AndroidRuntime(15364):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-01 14:24:21.256: E/AndroidRuntime(15364):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-01 14:24:21.256: E/AndroidRuntime(15364): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-01 14:24:21.256: E/AndroidRuntime(15364):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-01 14:24:21.256: E/AndroidRuntime(15364):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-01 14:24:21.256: E/AndroidRuntime(15364):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3039)
06-01 14:24:21.256: E/AndroidRuntime(15364):    ... 24 more
06-01 14:24:21.256: E/AndroidRuntime(15364): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: ""
06-01 14:24:21.256: E/AndroidRuntime(15364):    at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
06-01 14:24:21.256: E/AndroidRuntime(15364):    at java.lang.StringToReal.parseFloat(StringToReal.java:289)
06-01 14:24:21.256: E/AndroidRuntime(15364):    at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:300)
06-01 14:24:21.256: E/AndroidRuntime(15364):    at com.tip.ping.TippingActivity.calculateNumbers(TippingActivity.java:47)
06-01 14:24:21.256: E/AndroidRuntime(15364):    ... 27 more
```

My code is:

```
 public class TippingActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
    public void calculateNumbers(View view) {
        EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_bill);             
        String value;
        value = text.getText().toString();      
        float bill = Float.parseFloat(value);
        BigDecimal billbd;
        billbd = new BigDecimal(bill);


        EditText text2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_tip);
        String value2;
        value2 = text2.getText().toString();    
        if(!value2.contains("."))
            value2 = "."+value2;
        float tip = Float.parseFloat(value2);
        BigDecimal tipbd;
        tipbd = new BigDecimal(tip);


        EditText text3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_people);
        String value3;
        value3 = text3.getText().toString();

        TextView answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer);
        String answers;
        answers = answer.getText().toString();
        float answerf = Float.parseFloat(answers);
        BigDecimal answerbd;
        answerbd = new BigDecimal(answerf);
        answerbd.setScale(2);   
        TextView quick_answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quick_answer);
        String qanswers;
        qanswers = quick_answer.getText().toString();
        float qanswerf = Float.parseFloat(qanswers);
        BigDecimal qanswerbd;
        qanswerbd = new BigDecimal(qanswerf);       

        float l3 = Float.parseFloat(value3);
        BigDecimal l3bd;
        l3bd = new BigDecimal(l3);

        qanswerbd = billbd.multiply(tipbd).add(billbd);
        qanswerbd.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        String resultbd;
        resultbd = qanswerbd.toString();   

        quick_answer.setText(resultbd);     
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like an empty float value, but hard to say without line numbers ( Line 47 is...? )

> Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: ""

```
EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_bill);
String value = text.getText().toString();
```

Does anything come back if you Log/Print `value` at this point?

Comment: I'm sorry, I am new to android. What does "Log/Print value"? Thanks for answering and sorry about the line numbers.

Comment: Log.d("Appname", "Value: " + value); and watch the Logcat to see the value printed at runtime. It's sorta like System.out.println() in normal java. (You could also use System.out if you really want to). Check the value and make sure it's not an empty string, which will throw a number format exception in  your Float.parseFloat(value).

Comment: Thanks. I checked and the number came out so it must be another input field.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to parse a float from an empty string. You will want to do some sanity checking on your inputs before using them, or at least surround functions like Float.parseFloat, that can fail with a Try-Catch(In this case for NumberFormatException) that provides some sort of useful feedback for the user(a toast, maybe).

Comment: Thanks, I will check the inputs again.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have declared TippingActivity in AndroidManifest.xml ?